# PHP get PID of process and kill it

Tags: php

I've got a script to download a torrent file i'm using ctorrent which doesn't seem to close itself so i need to kill the pid.

```
$command = "ctorrent -x \"/var/www/html/torrents/$torrentName\"";
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

This works perfectly, i saw on another stackoverflow question someone said to do the following:

```
$command =  'yourcommand' . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!; ';
$pid = exec($command, $output);
var_dump($pid);
```

but when i use this it removes the output of the downloading file part which i need as im getting some data from the output.

How can i just get the pid from running my script?

This is ultimately what i'm trying to achieve:

```
if (file_exists( "/proc/$pid" )){
    shell_exec("kill -9 $pid");
}
```

Comment: You can use ps tool or use lock files. For ps `exec("ps -ef | grep '$process'", $output);` and parse $output

Comment: What would be contained in `$process` ?

Comment: `ctorrent` i suppose ?

Comment: Great to see someone using ctorrent. Lovely little application. :-) But instead of trying to find things by pid, why not use [CTCS](http://www.rahul.net/dholmes/ctorrent/ctcs.html) to control your ctorrent processes?  Much cleaner. Just run a CTCS instance, then tell each client to send its updates there. You get a centralized web GUI that lets you adjust settings, kill off old torrents, all handling ctorrent instances running on multiple servers.

Comment: Yeah ctorrent is great, CTCS sounds complicated. I'm happy with the way it downloads currently it's just the processes never seem to end so if i can kill them once downloaded it would be perfect

Comment: `$command =  'yourcommand' . '  & echo $!; ';` will get you pid of your torrent, but idk how to see if it's finished.

Comment: Where will the pid be stored under $command? I still need to see all the downloading text aswell as storing the $pid in a separate variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way i did it in the end, thanks for everyone's advice, i noticed when i did what ineersa said and put `. ' & echo $!; ';` at the end it would add the PID at the start of my output text, So then i just captured the first line of the output and it works great.

```
$command = "ctorrent -x \"/var/www/html/torrents/$torrentName\"";
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "<pre>";
echo $output;
echo "</pre>";

$pid = strtok($output, "\n");
echo $pid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try the `pgrep` command.

```
$command = "pgrep programname";
$pid = shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: Only problem with that is if i'm downloading 5 torrents at the same time, How will i know which one to kill?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following solution:

```
$command = 'ctorrent -x "/var/www/html/torrents/'.$torrentName.'"';
$outputfile = "output.out";
$pidfile = "pidfile.pid";
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $command, $outputfile, $pidfile));
$pid = file_get_contents($pidfile);
$outout = file_get_contents($outputfile);
```

You can kill the process as you wrote:

```
if (file_exists( "/proc/$pid" )) {
    shell_exec("kill -9 $pid");
}
```