# Putting command in background and get the PID via PHP exec()?

Tags: php, linux

When I manually run this command via SSH:

```
xx@xxx.com [~/public_html/xxx]# ls > ls2.out 2>&1 &
[1] 15205
```

Which simply returns the PID of the background process which in this case is 15205. However when I tried to do the same via PHP code:

```
$run = "ls > ls2.out 2>&1 &";
$return = exec($run, $output, $return_var);
echo '=====', PHP_EOL;
echo var_dump($run);
echo var_dump($return);
echo print_r($output);
echo print_r($return_var);
echo '=====', PHP_EOL;
```

It doesn't return the PID but just an empty string:

```
=====
string(19) "ls > ls2.out 2>&1 &"
string(0) ""
Array
(
)
101=====
```

Why?

How can I get the PID of the background process via PHP exec()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975328/php-get-pid-of-process-and-kill-it

Comment: @samayo Adding ' echo $!; ' to the end of the command as "ls > ls2.out 2>&1 & echo $!; " worked. However, is the & ampersand used as a command connector or as putting to background here? Is the command put to background at all in this case?

Comment: Yes, I believe so... I can't try it now, also I use screen/nohup but you should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `proc_open` for subprocess, and [`proc-get-statu`](http://php.net/manual/function.proc-get-status.php)s to get the pid.  for exec refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807556/is-it-possible-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-launched-by-exec-in-windows-xp).

```
<?php
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),
        2 => array("pipe", "w")
    );
    $command = 'ping -c 10 stackoverflow.com';

    $process = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
    echo 'hahaha';
```

Comment: Does proc_open() also work to put the process to background? We are running processes that would last hours and even days. Is it OK with proc_open()?

Comment: certainly, and it have more function.

Comment: but it seems to be mandatory to proc_close() the process before the PHP script ends or it will be a deadlock. However what I want is start a process in the background which keeps running even if my PHP script ends. Do I still need to proc_close() it explicitly?

Comment: @kavoir.com I've add a test code, you can make it a file test.php then test it with php test.php.