# How to call a function without wait it finishes in php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I use Laravel framework in my project.

I need call a function in PHP but I don't need wait for this.

For example:

```
public function payment($Authority)
{
   if (test == 1)
       $this -> one($Authority); // don't wait for this call.
   return view ("site.payment");

}

private function one($Authority)
{
   // php code
   // python code
}
```

Comment: PHP doesn't work this way.

Comment: Hi, @axiac , Really? solution do you have?

Comment: try sleep() function

Comment: Hi @A.ANoman, How to use sleep() function in my code?

Comment: [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) doesn't help here. It only pauses the script execution for some amount of time (in seconds).

Comment: There are a couple of ways (using [`pcntl_fork()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) or [program execution functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php)) that create a new process. The new process runs independent and it can continue running after the current script completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a queue job system. You could create a job to call that code and have your `payment` method dispatch the job to the queue for processing. (assuming you don't use the `sync` driver).

> "Queues allow you to defer the processing of a time consuming task, such as sending an email, until a later time. Deferring these time consuming tasks drastically speeds up web requests to your application." - [Laravel 5.3 Docs - Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues)

```
public function payment($Authority)
{
    if (test == 1) {
        // send to queue for processing later
        dispatch(new SomeJob($Authority));
    }

    return view ("site.payment");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for help me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use PThreads extension (http://php.net/pthreads):

```
<?php
// create your own class from Thread
class MyWorkerThreads extends Thread
{
    private $workerId;
    private $authority;

    public function __construct($id, $authority)
    {
        $this->workerId = $id;
        $this->authority = $authority;
    }

    // main function
    public function run()
    {
        echo "Worker #{$this->workerId} ran" . PHP_EOL;
        echo $authority;

        // make some long run tasks
        $html = file_get_contents('http://google.com?q=testing');
    }
}

...
$worker = new WorkerThreads($i, $Authority);
// start new thread with long run task
$worker->start();
...
// You can wait for the job to be finished at any time, using join
$worker->join();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call another process to run the code with proc_open. You also can write it into a artisan command, then call the command run in another process.

Here is a example for use [proc_open()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41679603/6521116)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The linked answer also doesn't provide any hint about how to answer to this question.